# the_meta() produces empty output

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to print out the meta infos of a post in my custom template. But both the functions `the_meta()` and `get_post_meta($id, $key, $single)` print out nothing. I have double checked that my post *has post meta data*, I have checked that in the DBs table.

Template:

```
<?php the_meta(); ?>
```

Output:

```
<ul class='post-meta'> </ul>
```

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Are you inside the loop? Anyway, echo get_post_meta should work, are you sure you have "echoed" the get_meta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something else was the problem: I named my custom fields `_fieldname`. That makes them hidden and unable to be accessed in the template. You have to write a "getter tag" to access them.

So I either have to remove the underscore or I have to write a function like `the_custom_field_foobar()` to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right but you need to remember that in php you have to use the `echo` function when you use get_post_meta($args)...

So, in your template you would be doing something like:

```
<ul class="meta thumb">
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) ?>
</ul>
```

Where `thumb` would be the value of the meta key you want to display...

Does that help?